# Google Drive and IIS Permissions

Tags: iis, permissions, drive

Senario, Google Shared drive full of documents, shared with the IIS server, server has a virtual directory pointed to a folder that is available locally on the IIS server.

Using Dropbox, I can set Security options on the folder and the IIS server has access to the folder, works great.  Company wants to move to Google Drive, when I attempt this, the Google drive folder has not Security Tab option.
[image: With Dropbox "Security Tab" Available]

[image: With Google Drive "Security Tab" Missing]

I have scoured around for answers but everything is about the API, this has nothing to do with the API.

I also created an account on the IIS server, gave the account Administration privilege's and I get this error: "Specified user cannot access path (d:\Shared\GoogleDrive).

Also, I setup d:\Shared because I can apply Security settings to the folder and was hoping it would propagate down but it does not.

Comment: The mechanism of such file sharing solutions (Google Drive/OneDrive/Dropbox) is not clearly documented, and all of them change heavily how those folders work under the hood. Thus, never create an IIS site that points to such a folder as it can fail miserably. Don't assume your simple changes in file/folder properties can help as there are quite a few other things running behind the scene.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions however I did figure out how to make Google Drive work the desired way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this:

1. On the server itself backup/sync the folder desired.  This allows you to manage the security on the folder, which is lost with other approaches.
2. From the google drive web interface, select computers, select the desired folder and using the more options from the menu, "Add shortcut to Drive".
3. You can then share it across the companies established share structure as a shortcut and sync files easily to the webserver.

In my case these are forms and pdf files but the webserver needs security access to the folder and using the base line Google shares did not work for me.  This way did.