# Adding Google Drive/One Drive as external storage for an IIS application

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-directory, google-drive-shared-drive

We host several applications under IIS and each of them have the ability to upload resources. We have a few clients who wish to increase their storage allocations which is not an easy task given these are physical servers with limited storage capacity.

I am yet to test, but I figure one option is that we create a Google Drive account, map it as another drive on the server, and then set virtual directories to the folders. We could segment off a different folder for each client, and this would prevent unwanted sharing between client folders. BUT, it would also be good to have the ability to let a client manage their cloud storage themselves, and provide us access to read/write to it.

In the second option, I can't imagine them giving us access to actually map this as a drive, nor would we want various drives mapped, but is there a way we could set a virtual directory to an external folder URL, e.g. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/blablabla?usp=sharing

I tried to setup a virtual directory with a URL like this but it falls over because of the "?" in the URL. I can't see a clear option for how we would pass in credentials to obtain access, other than building an OAuth2 application to handle this?

Is the mapped drive really the only option?

**EDIT:**

So I went down the path of installing Google Drive desktop and added a virtual directory to it, but it doesn't work. I get a permission denied error, and when I try to set the security on the folder, the "security" tab does not exist. I saw another [post about this same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73694685/google-drive-and-iis-permissions), but unfortunately their solution doesn't do what I need. I think this might work if you simply want to backup files to Google Drive, but I want to physically remove the storage from the server and outsource it to the cloud.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: IIS does not support any kind of mapped drives, so don't waste any time there. If "physical servers with limited storage capacity" are all you get, then try your best to add more storage to the servers themselves or add a compatible storage unit. Most premium storage solutions from Microsoft partners are compatible with IIS.

Comment: @LexLi are you referring to a NAS?

Comment: Microsoft IIS does not allow mapped drives to be used as virtual directories, so mapped drives are not a viable solution. Drive mapping is based on the credentials of the currently logged in user, whereas Microsoft IIS must work under the permissions of a specified user, usually ASPNET or IUSR_MACHINENAME, both of which are local to the computer and do not have permission to access network drives.